# Magento 2: What is the proper way to apply patch inside m2-hotfixes directory?

Tags: magento2, patches

I searched on google and found a patch. I created the patch dilw and placed it into m2-hotfixes directory.

Can Anyone help on it?.

Which Command I should use to apply the patch file inside that directory?

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.4.1. I think I know what need to be done, thanks for looking up my question.

Comment: No problem, anytime! And good luck!

Answer (score 5):

m2-hotfixes is used for magento cloud

You can follow these steps:

Step 1: create folder m2-hotfixes in the project root

Step 2: run in commandline  php ./vendor/bin/ece-patches apply

Answer (score 1):

by using Magento Quality Patches (MQP), I can apply the patch by using

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047139492

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/patching/mqp.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-patch.html